# php Composer windows install weird directory error

Tags: php, windows, directory, installation, composer-php

Okay, I am a really big noob for windows, Today I wanted to install composer for the first time and I ran into weird directory errors, when I select my php path for the php.exe

[image]

[image]

[image]

And it keeps going on and on with more 8 other extension.

So i am running `easyphp`, php exe folder selected correctly, selected from `C:\EasyPHP\php\php546x121016161819\php.exe` where easyphp is installed

I was googleing hard core but wasn't able to find any solution to this issue, so if someone would help me out on this or give me a hint it would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution for it, it wasn't a typo, easyphp install it self with default errors, and I had to make a few workarounds to make it work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the errors were, and how you fixed them?

Comment: You can find it here :) http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/3848/error-on-windows-with-easyphp

Comment: Thanks! Haven't got it working quite yet, but I've been able to at least get rid of the error alerts that kept popping up.  I'll keep working at it :)

Comment: to be honest, if you are not able to deal with it, i made an upgrade on my easyphp had to start all over agein with new errors, so i got mad backup my projects and installed the latest XAMPP, everything installed with out any errors like a charm, so im ok now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo in your path.  If your php folder is C:\EasyPHP\php\php546x121016161819\, your path shouldn't be pointing at c:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver\php\php546...

It should be ...c:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom\802.11\Driver
**\;c:**
\php\php546...